Mac Studio: Identifying USB Device Waking System
I have a new Mac Studio (M2 Max) and I've connected the USB hubs which used to be connected to my PC will all my peripherals.
This computer - unlike the Windows one - will now wake up within seconds of going to sleep, every single time; I've had about 400 sleep/wake cycles since yesterday. Every one of these also wakes up both my displays and I'm trying to figure out why.
When I run this:
pmset -g log | grep ' Wake  ' -A10 -B10

I get this output:
2024-09-29 21:59:55 -0600 Assertions            PID 503(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context130993.preventuseridlesleep" 00:03:03  id:0x0x100009dec [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:55 -0600 Assertions            PID 503(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context130986.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:03:03  id:0x0x500009ddf [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:55 -0600 Assertions            PID 503(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context130986.preventuseridlesleep" 00:03:03  id:0x0x100009dde [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:55 -0600 Assertions            PID 503(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context130996.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:03:03  id:0x0x500009df3 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:55 -0600 Assertions            PID 503(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context130996.preventuseridlesleep" 00:03:03  id:0x0x100009df2 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Assertions            PID 434(powerd) TurnedOn UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.kernel.useractive AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:kIOHIDSystemActivityTickle nxEvent: 0x" 00:00:00  id:0x0x9000085d3 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Assertions            PID 434(powerd) TurnedOn UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.kernel.useractive AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:kIOHIDSystemActivityTickle nxEvent: 0x" 00:00:00  id:0x0x9000085d3 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Assertions            PID 434(powerd) TurnedOn UserIsActive "com.apple.powermanagement.kernel.useractive AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:kIOHIDSystemActivityTickle nxEvent: 0x" 00:00:00  id:0x0x9000085d3 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Assertions            PID 489(WindowServer) Created PreventSystemSleep "com.apple.WindowServer.PUIDS" 00:00:00  id:0x0x70000a27e [System: PrevIdle PrevSleep DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Notification          Display is turned on                                                                  
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 smc.70170000 smc.70200000 USB2_plug/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:0%) 81 secs   
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 WakeDetails           DriverReason:SMC.OutboxNotEmpty - DriverDetails:                           
DriverReason:smc.70070000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:smc.70170000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:smc.70200000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:USB2_plug - DriverDetails:                                    
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 HibernateStats        hibmode=0 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        423           
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.889 sec                                                                   
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [usbsmartcardread timed out(30000 ms)] [dispext2:dcpav-video-interface- driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(103 ms)] 
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [Port-USB-C driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(57 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(78 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(75 ms)] [AppleDCPDPTXRemotePortProxy driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(84 ms)] [usb-drd1-port-hs driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(100 ms)] [usb-drd3-port-hs driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(117 ms)] [usb-drd1-port-ss driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 3)(105 ms)] [AppleDCPDPTXRemotePortProxy driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(120 ms)] [AppleT6020PCIe driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(292 ms)] [usb-drd3-port-ss driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 3)(191 ms)] [IOPP driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(201 ms)] [pci-bridge2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(201 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(494 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(496 ms)] [AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIASMedia3142 driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(331 ms)] [AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtion113 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(155 ms)] [Port-USB-C driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(53 ms)] [RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(80 ms)] [AppleCS42L84Audio driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(76 ms)] [Codec Output driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 1)(76 ms)] [AppleDCPDPTXRemotePortProxy driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(86 ms)] [usb-drd1-port-hs driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(98 ms)] [usb-drd3-port-hs driver is slow(msg: SetState to 3)(67 ms)] [usb-drd1-port-ss driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 3)(105 ms)] [AppleDCPDPTXRemotePortProxy driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(128 ms)] [AppleT6020PCIe driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(293 ms)] [usb-drd3-port-ss driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 3)(241 ms)] [IOPP driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(202 ms)] [pci-bridge2 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(202 ms)] [AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(494 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(497 ms)] [AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIASMedia3142 driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(331 ms)] [AppleEthernetAquantiaAqtion113 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(160 ms)]           
2024-09-29 21:59:56 -0600 Assertions            PID 434(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a280 [System: PrevIdle PrevSleep DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]  

Clearly a USB device is waking it up, but I can't figure out why. I can't even figure out which device.
How do I identify which device USB2_plug/UserActivity is (without systematically unplugging everything and spending hours watching whether or not it wakes up)?

It looks like the device with location ID 0x0x9000085d3 is causing the wake events. You can search for that identifier in the USB section of the System Information window, or in the output of system_profiler SPUSBDataType.

After posting my question I removed my Yubikey and it stopped... and when I plugged it back in I no longer had a device with that ID, so I don't know for sure whether that was it or not. However, the computer still loves to wake randomly... Just today, while I was at work, it woke up the monitors 12 times. I understand it goes from Deep Idle to Dark Wake and back a lot, but the fact that it keeps turning on the displays is completely unacceptable and I can't figure out how to get it to stop...
